# How to add delay to loading screen in Sencha app?

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch

I am developing a `sencha app` and i want to add delay to default sencha blue splash screen. I am doing it for browser not for native app. Any help will be highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask proper questions!

Comment: Sorry and thanks SubliemeSiem. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Which Version of Sencha Touch are you Using ?

Comment: I am using ST 2.4.2 and Sencha Cmd sencha-5.0.3.324